# Add login by email

Tags: support, login, my-logins

I've created my account a couple of years ago using the Google login. Is it possible to add a new login method just by email and password?
At the "Add new login" screen, I don't see this option.

Comment: eventually it's possible by using "forgot password" on the login screen, and set new password through my email address. But there doesn't seem to be a possibility to add a password at the "add more logins" page